# Failed to invoke Method. Message payload is of type: String

Tags: java, mule, connector

I have created a mule connector using Devkit, it just accepts a string, when i tried to run the mule application by using the connector , it throuws "Failed to invoke myProcessor. Message payload is of type: String". what should i do?

[image]

```
Exception stack is:
1. Parameter username in method connect can't be null because is not @Optional (org.mule.modules.duoasset.connection.UnableToAcquireConnectionException)
  org.mule.modules.duoasset.connectivity.DuoAssetConnectorConnectionManager:260 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/modules/duoasset/connection/UnableToAcquireConnectionException.html)
2. Failed to invoke myProcessor. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.devkit.processor.DevkitBasedMessageProcessor:128 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.modules.duoasset.connection.UnableToAcquireConnectionException: Parameter username in method connect can't be null because is not @Optional
    at org.mule.modules.duoasset.connectivity.DuoAssetConnectorConnectionManager.getEvaluatedConnectionKey(DuoAssetConnectorConnectionManager.java:260)
    at org.mule.modules.duoasset.connectivity.DuoAssetConnectorConnectionManager.getEvaluatedConnectionKey(DuoAssetConnectorConnectionManager.java:39)
    at org.mule.modules.duoasset.process.ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.execute(ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.java:58)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Can you post more of the stack trace?

Comment: +1 for expert paintbrush skillz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the stacktrace you need to pass in the connection attributes on the connector. In this case "username". So on your connector config you should add the username attribute:

```
<duoasset:connector name="DuoAsset" username="myusername" password="my password" />
```

And so on for each global parameter or parameter in your @Connect method.

If they are connection parameters, you can also pass them on the operation itself:

```
<duoasset:myprocessor content="#[payload]" username="myusername" password="my password" />
```

Also if you do not need any connection management you can just remove the @Connect and @Disconnect methods etc.

See more on connection management here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Implementing+Connection+Management

Comment: one more favor! how can you return an argument through a connector and how can a flow access the out argument of first connector?

Comment: You just use standard java return something; that matches the return type of your method signature. Mule will make whatever you return the payload for the next processor in your flow.